# Predicate not excluding data as expected

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I’m having an issue that I just can’t figure out. As a caveat I've had to scrub data pretty hard so excuse any XML formatting irregularities please.

It appears my predicate isn’t excluding data as I’d expect. I want to only write some data if there are contracts that start in a given month, however, when I build my for-each (or apply-template, or if, or... ) statement that seeks to exclude contracts outside of the month the xsl seems to return data regardless of the year. It does appear to exclude starts outside of the given month, but that might be coincidence.

The XSLT with a for-each example. I'm going to need this (or apply-template) so this is the core of my issue I think. Again, excuse irregularities. This isn't how I would leave it, but it works for a fast test.

```
<xsl:variable name="reportStartMonth" select="xs:date(contracts/exportinformation/timestamp/TIMESTAMP/@date) - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', day-from-date(contracts/exportinformation/timestamp/TIMESTAMP/@date), 'D')) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
<xsl:variable name="reportEndMonth" select="xs:date(contracts/exportinformation/timestamp/TIMESTAMP/@date) - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', day-from-date(contracts/exportinformation/timestamp/TIMESTAMP/@date) - 1, 'D')) + xs:yearMonthDuration('P1M') - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
<xsl:key name="costGroup" match="contracts/Contract/ContractDetails/RightGroup/cost/costGroup/COSTGROUP" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$reportStartMonth"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$reportEndMonth"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="contracts/Contract/ContractDetails[Rights/Window/startDateFormula/fixedDate/DATE/@date &gt;= $reportStartMonth and Rights/Window/startDateFormula/fixedDate/DATE/@date &lt;= $reportEndMonth]/RightGroup/cost/costGroup/COSTGROUP[generate-id() = generate-id(key('costGroup', @name)[1])]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../../../../@contractNumber"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../../../Rights/Window/startDateFormula/fixedDate/DATE/@date"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

When run against the following XML:

```
<contracts>
    <exportinformation>
        <timestamp>
            <TIMESTAMP time="14:08:22.889" date="2018-01-17"/>
        </timestamp>
    </exportinformation>
    <Contract contractName="C1" contractNumber="00000001">
        <ContractDetails>
            <RightGroup>
                <cost>
                    <costGroup>
                        <COSTGROUP name="A1"/>
                    </costGroup>
                </cost>
            </RightGroup>
            <Rights>
                <Window>
                    <startDateFormula>
                        <fixedDate>
                            <DATE date="2018-01-01"/>
                        </fixedDate>
                    </startDateFormula>
                </Window>
            </Rights>
        </ContractDetails>
    </Contract>
    <Contract contractName="C2" contractNumber="00000002">
        <ContractDetails>
            <RightGroup>
                <cost>
                    <costGroup>
                        <COSTGROUP name="A1"/>
                    </costGroup>
                </cost>
            </RightGroup>
            <Rights>
                <Window>
                    <startDateFormula>
                        <fixedDate>
                            <DATE date="2013-01-01"/>
                        </fixedDate>
                    </startDateFormula>
                </Window>
            </Rights>
        </ContractDetails>
    </Contract>
    <Contract contractName="C3" contractNumber="0000003">
        <ContractDetails>
            <RightGroup>
                <cost>
                    <costGroup>
                        <COSTGROUP name="A2"/>
                    </costGroup>
                </cost>
                <cost>
                    <costGroup>
                        <COSTGROUP name="A2"/>
                    </costGroup>
                </cost>
            </RightGroup>
            <Rights>
                <Window>
                    <startDateFormula>
                        <fixedDate>
                            <DATE date="2017-01-01"/>
                        </fixedDate>
                    </startDateFormula>
                </Window>
                <Window>
                    <startDateFormula>
                        <fixedDate>
                            <DATE date="2019-01-01"/>
                        </fixedDate>
                    </startDateFormula>
                </Window>
            </Rights>
        </ContractDetails>
        <ContractDetails>
            <RightGroup>
                <cost>
                    <costGroup>
                        <COSTGROUP name="A2"/>
                    </costGroup>
                </cost>
            </RightGroup>
            <Rights>
                <Window>
                    <startDateFormula>
                        <fixedDate>
                            <DATE date="2017-11-01"/>
                        </fixedDate>
                    </startDateFormula>
                </Window>
            </Rights>
        </ContractDetails>
    </Contract>
</contracts>
```

I expected this to return the first and last dates for January, which it does quite nicely and then the line:

```
A1  00000001    2018-01-01
```

However, it actually returns

```
A1  00000001    2018-01-01
A2  0000003 2017-01-01 2019-01-01
```

The date comparison predicate is something I've used across several stylesheets without an issue. However, it has always been part of a value-of|sum or choose|when statement as far as I can remember. Though I've written hundreds of stylesheets in the past year so I might have used it in a for-each or apply-template somewhere. Is there some operation within the for-each and key that I'm not properly taking into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that one of your `Rights` elements has two `DATE` elements as descendants, and you current logic is considering both at the same time. So, one date is `2017-01-01` which is less than the report end date, and the other date is `2019-01-01` which is after the report start date. The logic in your current expression results in the expression being true.

What you want is for it to check if just one of the dates satisfies both conditions, so it should be this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="contracts/Contract/ContractDetails
                      [Rights/Window/startDateFormula/fixedDate/DATE/@date
                          [xs:date(.) &gt;= $reportStartMonth and xs:date(.) &lt;= $reportEndMonth]]
                      /RightGroup/cost/costGroup/COSTGROUP[generate-id() = generate-id(key('costGroup', @name)[1])]">
```

Note, it looks like you are trying to do Muenchian Groupin too. As you are using  XSLT 2.0, consider using `xsl:for-each-group` instead, which would remove the scary part of the expression that uses generate-id().

Comment: Thank you Tim! I had three other devs looking at this and we all missed what it was doing with the two DATE elements.